# how do i stop my app from running on Virtualbox?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have tried [this unit](http://www.delphigeist.com/2011/01/udgvmutils-version-11-thanks-to-chee.html) to detect if my application is running in Oracle VirtualBox, but it is not detecting VirtualBox.

I have tested it with Windows 7 installed in VirtualBox.

Is there any efficient way to prevent my VCL application from running in VirtualBox?

Comment: Did you try debugging the code to figure out why it doesn't detect VirtualBox? There is a comment on the download: "*This code does not detect Virtual Box if Windows 8 is installed?*", so perhaps the VirtualBox detection is just broken in general? Looking at the detection code, it is actually very trivial code - it simply tests if `VBoxHook.dll` or `\\.\VBoxMiniRdrDN` exists on the system the app is running on. Perhaps your version of VirtualBox does not have those items?

Comment: What is special about virtual box? You want to block it but not other virtual machines. Virtual machines are the future. Trying to block them will cripple the utility of your software.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Lack of minimum required hardware/software support comes to mind.  Anything that (at least currently) requires DX10+ or OpenGL3.0+ won't work properly, for example.  That said, the software should rightly test for the specific requirements it needs, if that's the case, rather than circuitously assuming support from some other indicator like whether it's in a VM or not... surely the support in VirtualBox will change over time.

Comment: Virtual box for development is for sure needed , but in case my application will need to read HDID as unique use then the Virtualbox will be a break through the functions that needed

Comment: Doesn't sound right to me. Sounds like you are implementing some sort of software licensing.

Comment: You should not block virtual machines in general. Check for features you mentioned before. "is dx10 available" or  "is opengl supported".

Comment: Sounds to me like:"I want to make a licensing module for my app which depends on harddisk id. This doesn't work in virtualbox so I decided my app can't be used on virtualbox at all."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use The [Win32_BaseBoard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394072(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI class and check if the Product string contains the word "`Virtual`"

For example :

```
function _IsOSVirtual(): Boolean;
const
  v = 'virtual';
Begin
  Result := False;
  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
     if Pos(v, LowerCase(GetWin32_BaseBoard('Product'))) > 0 then
      Result := True;
  finally
    CoUninitialize;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: VMWare from v8 on also has [440BX Desktop Reference Platform](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/409703)

Answer (score 0):

If you can obtain Bios Information (with WMI or other method) you can find Traces of VirtualBox.

```
instance of Win32_BIOS
{
    ...
    BIOSVersion = {"VBOX   - 1"};
    Caption = "Default System BIOS";
    Description = "Default System BIOS";
    Manufacturer = "innotek GmbH";
    Name = "Default System BIOS";
    SerialNumber = "0";
    SMBIOSBIOSVersion = "VirtualBox";
    SMBIOSPresent = TRUE;
    SoftwareElementID = "Default System BIOS";
    SoftwareElementState = 3;
    Status = "OK";
    Version = "VBOX   - 1";
};
```

Continuing with WMI other classes can help you to identify VirtualBox installation. For example this Query:

```
Select Manufacturer, Model, OEMStringArray from Win32_ComputerSystem
```

Return this values:

```
instance of Win32_ComputerSystem
{
    Manufacturer = "innotek GmbH";
    Model = "VirtualBox";
    OEMStringArray = {"vboxVer_5.1.22", "vboxRev_115126"};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function IsRunningVirtualBox : Boolean;
var
   vHandle : THandle;
begin
   Result := false;
   vHandle := LoadLibrary('VBoxHook.dll');
   if vHandle <> 0 then begin
      Result := true;
      FreeLibrary(vHandle);
   end;
end;
```